# Hide DetaiViewController in UISplitViewController in portrait orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

i want know if it's possibile to hide the DetailViewController in portrait orientation for the UISplitController template ipad example, and let use the MasterViewController in full screen in portrait orientation, and when the orientation change to landascape use the normal UISplitViewController view, with masterview on the left and detail view on the right...it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's UISplitViewController has been given a very specific behavior, and cannot be customized this way...

In my company, we had to implement our own SplitViewController - our intent was to handle different display of 'masterViewController' when in portrait orientation, different sizes for both controllers in landscape orientation (than those allowed by UISplitViewController), and a different way to handle 'masterViewController' display in portrait orientation -

This heavy customization led us to deal with all kinds of problems regarding UIViewController containing others UIViewControllers  - (UIViewControllers containement wasn't supported by Apple before iOS 5 ! see [CoconutKit on Github](https://github.com/defagos/CoconutKit/tree/master/CoconutKit/Sources/ViewControllers), or [this example](http://www.merowing.info/2012/02/uiviewcontroller-containment/) for workaround examples...).

For your specific needs, here's [Matt Gemmell's own attempt at implementing custom SplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/) , it's quite good, you can still fork the code to make it fit your own needs.